# AS3 TextField use hand cursor WITH enabled mouseChildren

Tags: actionscript-3, click, parent-child, textfield, movieclip

What I'm trying to do is; upon clicking a textfield, a function runs which uses the text in the textfield as the URL for a URLRequest and sends you to another page. It works perfectly, but I want the cursor to switch to a hand upon hovering over the textfield.

I was able to do this by adding them as Children to a MovieClip with buttonMode and useHandCursor enabled, but I had to set MovieClip.mouseChildren to false for it to work. And that's where the problem lies; mouseChildren is disallowing me from going to the page...

I can't make the MovieClip parent go to the URL with the function, because there are multiple textfields, not just one, and I can't use e.target.text to get the URL from the textfield, because that gets the text property from the parent MovieClip instead...

Here's my code:

```
var handyMan:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
handyMan.useHandCursor = true;
handyMan.buttonMode = true;
handyMan.mouseChildren = false;

for each (var xit:TextField in linkus)
{
    xit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, useLink);
    handyMan.addChild(xit);
}

this.addChild(handyMan);

function useLink(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(e.target.text));
}
```

So, is there a way to enable mouseChildren **and** use a hand cursor at the same time?

Comment: updated my solution to something of which I'm pretty sure it will work, but it's a bit nasty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making the textfields not selectable?

`xit.selectable = false;`

That might allow you to not need to use mouseChildren.

Alternatively, if you receive the event from the textfield, make use of something like FunctionObject:

```
package {
/**
 * ...
 * @author Pimgd
 */

public class FunctionObject 
{
    private var f:Function;
    private var o:Object;
    private var args:Array;
    public function FunctionObject(func:Function, obj:Object, fArgs:Array) {
        f = func;
        o = obj;
        args = fArgs;
        if (args == null) {
            args = new Array();
        }
    }
    public function call(...rest):* {
        var a = args.concat();
        for each(var x in rest) {
            a.push(x);
        }
        var obj:Object = f.apply(o, a);
        if (obj != null) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    public function apply(target:Object, ...rest):* {
        return f.apply(target, rest);
    }
    public function setArgs(nArgs:Array):void {
        args = nArgs.concat();
    }
    public function getArgs():Array {
        return args;
    }
    public function getFunction():Function {
        return f;
    }
}
}
```

alter the forloop to be

```
for each (var xit:TextField in linkus)
{
    var f:FunctionObject = new FunctionObject(useLink, this, [xit]);
    xit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f.call);
    handyMan.addChild(xit);
}
```

Then, alter useLink to take a textfield...

```
function useLink(tf:TextField):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(tf.text));
}
```

And that should fix your problem. Yup, it's not nice. But it works.

What it does is it prepares a function call - useLink, with as argument the textfield. It attaches the trigger of that function to the eventListener, so that when that fires, the prepared functioncall is triggered.

Comment: The way the code is right now, on the question... if you click the textfield, which eventlistener is called? The textfield's or the movieclip's?

Comment: Right now, the textfield's.

Comment: I don't have a flash compiler here right now, so let me know if you get any errors with this code or if you need more explanation.